# Entity Framework Include persistence on next query

Tags: entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I am trying to do a conditional include query. I saw multiple options, one of them being with projection. I also need that I was able to access properties from the filtered list.

The relationship between entities are:

```
(Parent) 1-n (List of children) 1-1 (Grand Child)
```

I tried the option whit projection and it worked, but I was unable to access the property from the filtered list. I lost a lot of time trying do make it works, and using "try and fail method" I manage to do it, but I notice something that I don't understand and it bother me a lot. Here is my code:

```
    public IQueryable<Parent> Parents()
    {
        GrandChildId = ....;

        _contextProvider.Context.Parents.Where(c => "condition").Include(b =>
            b.ChildrenList.Select(f => f.GrandChild)).ToList();    //PART 1------------------

        var parentsList = _contextProvider.Context.Parents.Where(condition).Select(parents => new
                                                                        {
                                                                            Parents = parents,
                                                                            ChildrenList = parents.ChildrenList.Where(b => b.GrandChild.Id == GrandChildId),
                                                                        }
            ).ToList().Select(row =>
                {
                    var item = row.Parents;
                    item.ChildrenList = (ICollection<ChildrenList>)row.ChildrenList;
                    
                    return item;
                }
            ); //PART 2--------------------

        return parentsList.AsQueryable();
    }
```

If you ask me I consider "Part 1" irrelevant, but if I delete it and try to put the include on the "Part 2" is not working anymore (Grand Child is not longer accessible). It's seems that the include from the fist part persist to the second query.

All the navigation property are "virtual".

Comment: The entities are tracked by the context. When you execute a second query on the same context the relationships still exist.